# Make local playlist with songs from iTunes

Tags: ios, objective-c, playlist, itunes-api, iosdeployment

Is there any chance to search iTunes for songs and add them to the local playlist programmatically?

*BTW: I created local playlist successfully and got JSON but I don't know how to use it:*

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Gipsy+Kings+Bamboleo&country=US&media=music&entity=song"]];
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler: ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
    NSError *jsonError;
    NSDictionary *jsonResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];
}] resume];
```

Comment: Please check my answer. It may helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users configure playlists using iTunes on the desktop or by creating an on-the-go playlist on the device. To your iOS application, `(MPMediaPlaylist)`  playlists are **read-only**. so there is currently no way to create these through a 3rd-party app. The user can only do this with iTunes or through the built-in iOS Music app.

[Apple Ref Link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mediaplayer/mpmediaplaylist)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @DZoki019 is this help you?